# Information about Kampegowda international lounge Bengaluru

Tags: airports, india, lounges

I'll be going from Bengaluru to Frankfurt, and I have a few questions about the lounge:

1. When can I enter into it?
2. How much is the fee? Is everything complimentary after paying the fee?

Thanks.

If one can direct me to where I can find up to date information on these, that'd also be appreciated.

Comment: From dragon pass I can see three lounges listed at 32 USD. Not sure if that's the general admission it only for dragon pass members.